# Android; How to define a larger # of playing pieces (chess, mahjong ...): Views? Bitmaps?

Tags: android

Is there a best-practice how to handle a larger number of playing pieces?
(Do I have to use imageViews for EACH piece?!?)

How would you make only the top one in a stack selectable/clickable?
(I am about to transform a game I wrote in javascript/xml to run on android phones.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a view for each piece.  You could give each view the same handler and then, since the handler passes the view that was clicked, check to see which view was clicked with a loop of if(pieceView == touchedView).

You could also override the

```
Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)
```

function.  This will give you the coords that were touched and from there you can figure out which piece was touched.  One thing to keep in mind is that the X and Y values will be in Pixels and that the screen resolution can change depending on the phone.  It would be good to convert these values into a resolution independent value before using them.

I performance wise view can be very slow, you shouldn't have too much trouble with that if you are making a traditional boardgame though.

Comment: The answer seems/ed well-thought and competent. It may be the best for my low-level project. But I'd like to point to the second answer by Romain Guy: He's a (senior?) software engineer at Google's android department - see below!

Answer (score 0):

I will answer "myself" because his is mainly a quote...

**Romain Guy,** software engineer at **Google** answered my direct question to him:

> Hi,
>
> Using one ImageView per game piece would be a bad idea :) Instead you should create a custom view and draw the pieces on the Canvas from the onDraw() method. This is much more efficient.

Thanks to Romain - I just wanted to share ***his*** comment with *everybody* interested!